# How can you run two python tkinter files simultaneously when one has a loop in it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a tkinter country guessing game witch works fine however takes along time to run. So i made a loading screen for it with a looping animation on in a separate file. I cant find a way to run the loading screen first and then run the game whilst the animation on the loading screen is still running.

Loading screen code:

```
from tkinter import *

from time import *
import os

import random

run = 0
loads = True
dotnum = 0
def task():
   
    sleep(2) 
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.title("Loading...")
root.geometry("1280x720")

Background = PhotoImage(file = "Images\Loadscreen.png")
Loaders = PhotoImage(file = "Images\Loader.gif")


image = Label(root,width=1000,height=500,image=Background)
image.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frameCnt = 16
frames = [PhotoImage(file='Images\Loader.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(frameCnt)]

def update(ind):
        frame = frames[ind]
        ind += 1
        if ind == frameCnt:
            ind = 0
        loadanim.configure(image=frame)
        root.after(100, update, ind)
loadanim = Label(root, bg = "black")
loadanim.place(x = 450, y = 450)

root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

To run the loading screen first, you can call the loading screen code before calling the game code.

You can modify the code to pass a function as an argument to the loading screen, and then call this function after the loading screen is destroyed. This will allow you to run the game code after the loading screen is done.

For example:

```
def run_game():
    # game code here
    pass

def run_loading_screen(callback):
    # loading screen code here
    root.after(2000, callback)
    root.mainloop()

run_loading_screen(run_game)
```

Here, `run_game` is the function containing the game code, and `run_loading_screen` is the function containing the loading screen code. The `run_loading_screen` function takes a callback argument, which is the function to be called after the loading screen is destroyed. In the loading screen code, the `root.after` method is used to call the callback function after 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds).